# iOS Flutter webview cookie session lost when navigating too quickly

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview

There seems to be a bug in iOS that is not occurring in android where sharing multiple webviews session data seems to get lost when navigating too quickly from one webview to the other. I have 3 tabs each of which are flutter webviews and on android when i login to one of the webviews I can navigate quickly between webviews without losing session cookies. On iOS the sessions are only lost if I navigate from one to another too fast, otherwise when navigating slowly there are no issues.

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';


class LatestView extends StatelessWidget {
  final ConnectivityResult connectivityResult;
  LatestView({this.connectivityResult}) {
    print(connectivityResult);
  }
  final Set<Factory> gestureRecognizer = [Factory(() => EagerGestureRecognizer(),)].toSet();
  final HelperService _helperService = locator<HelperService>();

  _startsLoading(String str) {
    print(str);
  }

  final Completer<WebViewController> _latestWebViewController =
      new Completer<WebViewController>();


  bool isLoading = true;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none)
          ? Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Image(
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                image: AssetImage('assets/ic_no_internet.png'),
              ),
            )
          : WebView(
        onPageStarted: _startsLoading('Loading'),
              key: _helperService.gimmeLatestKey,
              initialUrl: 'https://mywebsite.com',
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
          new Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                () => new EagerGestureRecognizer(),
          ),
        ].toSet(),
        onPageFinished: _startsLoading('Finished'),
            ),
    );



  }
}
```

Comment: You can also try my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) (which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews) and set to `true` the iOS-specific option `sharedCookiesEnabled`. You can also use the [`CookieManager`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#cookiemanager-class) class to manage the cookies used by your WebView instances.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. Are you saying I can just add your plugin, leave my app as is, and add a class or something which will solve the issue?

Comment: You can try! I don't know you use case exactly. However, classes are similar but not equal! For example `WebView` is called `InAppWebView` and `onPageFinished` is called `onLoadStop`. You can start using the basic `InAppWebView` example in `README.md` of the Github repo. Then, you can try to set `sharedCookiesEnabled: true` for iOS using `initialOptions`: `ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions( sharedCookiesEnabled: true )`.
However, just check the repository!

Comment: I ended up trying your inappwebview and it is amazing!! The only issue I am facing with your package is restoring the sessions when I reopen the application. For example if im logged in, close the app, and reopen it. I tried to search the repo for "restore" but cant find anything. Do you think you can point me in the right direction? @LorenzoPichilli

Comment: @brigitte18, did you resolve this problem? I faced the same and I really don't know how to fix it. Could you answer me pls?

Answer (score 0):

webview_flutter has improved since. I suggest trying it out again for your use case. The plugin now has support for setting and restoring cookies via CookieManager. More details are discussed on this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27597).

Answer (score 0):

Just set an expiration date for the cookie and it will be saved.